# Confusing regex behavior when combining ` with (

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, vim

In order to work around a mysql 5.0 to 5.1 compatibility issue, I'm trying to change this pattern:

```
KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`) USING BTREE
```

to this:

```
KEY `brand_id` USING BTREE (`brand_id`)
```

Running the following regex in vim locates all the occurrences of the issue:

```
KEY `.*` \(.*\) USING BTREE
```

So, I tried just modifying this to the following substitution string, but it can no longer locate the matching strings.  Why?

```
%s/KEY (`.*`) (\(.*\)) USING BTREE/KEY \1 USING BTREE (\2)/gc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but in Vim you need to escape the matching parentheses and leave them alone when they are to be taken literally. Try:

```
%s/KEY \(`.*`\) \((.*)\) USING BTREE/KEY \1 USING BTREE \2/gc
```

Comment: And I'll +1 anyone who tells me how to invert this odd behavior once and for all...

Comment: That did it.  I had some extra parens as well in the replace strings, so it ended up working with the following: %s/KEY \(`.*`\) \((.*)\) USING BTREE/KEY \1 USING BTREE \2/gc

Comment: If you enable ['very magic mode'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) in your search pattern then it inverts the escaping requirement, so that `()` groups and captures its contents, and a literal bracket match must be escaped `\(\)`. I find this more consistent with my experience of using regular expressions elsewhere, so prefer to always use very magic mode. In this case, the search pattern would be `\vKEY (`.*`) (\(.*\)) USING BTREE`.

Comment: @nelstrom: you made my day, this is great. Do you know of any way to make this the default?